# Facebook Graph API post isn't showing on the Facebook iOS app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a post that is being sent using a cron job with a long-lived access token. Everything works fine and the post publishes to my Page on the Facebook website. However, it does not show up on the Facebook iOS app in my timeline or on the Page.

I am using the Facebook PHP API:

```
$post =  array(
    'access_token' => [long-lived-token],
    'message' => 'message goes here...'
);
$facebook->api('/facebook-id/feed', 'POST', $post);
```

When I pull the Facebook posts for the page in the Graph API Explorer, all of the permissions look identical to those of posts made through Facebook itself:

```
"privacy": {
        "description": "Public", 
        "value": "EVERYONE", 
        "friends": "", 
        "networks": "", 
        "allow": "", 
        "deny": ""
      }
```

Thanks in advance for any insight anyone can give about this.

Comment: I have one app where posts show on Android native and Desktop, but not iOS. I have another app where posts show on all three. I can't find the difference either.

Comment: Would you mind posting anything you can about your "good" app? I'd love to try to find the issue.

Comment: The "good" app is simply a tester application I created on Facebook. From what I've seen, everything is the same. The only difference, is my "good" app is listed in the Settings->Applications in the iOS Facebook app, while my production app is not. I have no idea why my app isn't listed. I can make posts just fine. But the app isn't listed.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/1413312798925794/  is a bug I just filed. It really does seem like a config issue, since one app works. But I can't find a config difference. I also have to assume the code is working since I see the posts just fine in Android and Web.

Comment: Do you have a secure canvas for your app? I threw a <html></html> page on S3 for the secure URL for the canvas, and it started working.....